# To determine whether a number and any other two numbers in the array to form a continuous number of three

Tags: javascript, arrays

write a function like this:

```
function canFormContinuosNums(num, array);
//num is the target number, 
//array is the source array which contain some int number:
```

for example:

```
num = 1, 
array =[ 2,3,4,5,7,8,9,0];
```

the function must test weather the array contain two number such as 2,3 or 0,2, can form '012' or '123'.

The function must return false or true ;

if true return the two array ,like [2,3] or [0,2];

I tried a  lot, but neither work perfect.Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Show what you've tried and can hopefully help

Comment: sounds like a test

Comment: Neither the que is clear not any tried implementation

Comment: It's unclear what the function should return. First it says true or false. Then it says the 'two array', does that mean an array of all matching pairs, or just one pair? If it's just one pair, which one takes precedence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this one?

```js
function canFormContinuosNums(num, array) {
var tempArray = new Array();
var outputArray = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   tempArray[i] =  [num+i-2, num+i-1, num+i];
   tempArray[i].splice(tempArray[i].indexOf(num), 1);
   var check = 0;
   for (var k = 0; k < tempArray[i].length; k++) {
    if (array.includes(tempArray[i][k])) {
      check += 1;
    }
   }
   if (check == 2) {
    outputArray.push(tempArray[i]);
   }
  }
  console.log(outputArray);
  
};
num = 4, 
array =[2,3,4,5,7,8,9,0];
canFormContinuosNums(num, array);
```

Comment: So the accepted answer is a function that returns nothing ? And I'm surprised with the fact that none of those 3 answers got even +1

Comment: It does return `outputArray` actually. It's just printed into console. Instead of being returned. Even google does that. [Check this out](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/).

Comment: *Instead of being returned.* actual quote. Plus, you initialize `num` and `array` inside the function. Anyway what makes your answer good is the `new Array()` and the `.push(...)`

Comment: How did i miss that? I edited my previous answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Then your call to `canFormContinuosNums();` should be `canFormContinuosNums(num,array);` ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
function canFormContinuousNums(num, array){
    // array contains the 2 numbers before num
    if(array.indexOf(num-2)!=-1 && array.indexOf(num-1)!=-1){
        return [num-2,num-1];
    }
    // array contains the number before num AND the number after num
    else if(array.indexOf(num-1)!=-1 && array.indexOf(num+1)!=-1){
        return [num-1,num+1];
    }
    // array contains the 2 numbers after num
    else if(array.indexOf(num+1)!=-1 && array.indexOf(num+2)!=-1){
        return [num+1,num+2];
    }

    return false;
}
```

This should give you wether the array contains two numbers such as *you can form a continuous number of three*, and if you can, will return either the array containing the 2 previous numbers, or the one containing the one before and the one after, or the one containing the two next numbers.

You could also have a code for which combination is doable as :

```
0 -> no combination
1 -> the two previous numbers
2 -> the one before & the one after
4 -> the two next numbers
```

And then :

```
3 will give you both 1 & 2
5 will give you both 1 & 4 // note that 1 & 4 is impossible without 2
6 will give you both 2 & 4
7 will give you all three combinations.
```

As following :

```js
function canFormContinuousNums(num, array){
    var result = 0;
    // array contains the 2 numbers before num
    if(array.indexOf(num-2)!=-1 && array.indexOf(num-1)!=-1){
        result += 1;
    }
    // array contains the number before num AND the number after num
    if(array.indexOf(num-1)!=-1 && array.indexOf(num+1)!=-1){
        result += 2;
    }
    // array contains the 2 numbers after num
    if(array.indexOf(num+1)!=-1 && array.indexOf(num+2)!=-1){
        result += 4;
    }

    return result;
}

var array = [0,1,4,6,8,9,11,14,15,17,18];
console.log(canFormContinuousNums(20, array)); // no combination
console.log(canFormContinuousNums(2, array)); // [0,1]
console.log(canFormContinuousNums(5, array)); // [4,6]
console.log(canFormContinuousNums(10, array)); // [8,9] & [9,11]
console.log(canFormContinuousNums(13, array)); // [14,15]
console.log(canFormContinuousNums(7, array)); // [6,8] & [8,9]
console.log(canFormContinuousNums(16, array)); // [14,15] & [15,17] & [17,18]

// test function to display all the combinations switch the number and the result given by canFormContinuousNums
function displayResult(number,result){
  if(result & 1){
    console.log("["+(number-2)+","+(number-1)+"]");
  }
  if(result & 2){
    console.log("["+(number-1)+","+(number+1)+"]");
  }
  if(result & 4){
    console.log("["+(number+1)+","+(number+2)+"]");
  }
}

console.log("Test displayResult(16,7)");
displayResult(16,canFormContinuousNums(16,array));
```

---

Edit :
As you wish to get all the combinations, the following should work :

```js
function canFormContinuousNums(num, array){
  var flag = false;
  var result = [[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]];
  // array contains the 2 numbers before num
  if(array.indexOf(num-2)!=-1 && array.indexOf(num-1)!=-1){
    flag = true;
    result[0][0] = num-2;
    result[0][1] = num-1;
  }
  else{
    result[0] = false;
  }
  // array contains the number before num AND the number after num
  if(array.indexOf(num-1)!=-1 && array.indexOf(num+1)!=-1){
    flag = true;
    result[1][0] = num-1;
    result[1][1] = num+1;
  }
  else{
    result[1] = false;
  }
  // array contains the 2 numbers after num
  if(array.indexOf(num+1)!=-1 && array.indexOf(num+2)!=-1){
    flag = true;
    result[2][0] = num+1;
    result[2][1] = num+2;
  }
  else{
    result[2] = false;
  }

  if(flag == true){
    return result;
  }
  else{
    return false;
  }
}

var array2 = [0,1,2];
console.log(canFormContinuousNums(1,array2));
console.log(canFormContinuousNums(4,array2));
```

Comment: Please notice: *The function must return false or true*

Comment: And so what do we do for the *if true return the two array ,like [2,3] or [0,2];* part ? Plus, I do believe in your solution, *canMakeContinuous(array,5)* should answer *true* as the array contains 3 and 4 so you can make '345'.

Comment: True. Will update it. Also, I guess OP is only looking if its possible or not.

Comment: Hey I have updated my answer based on the test case you mentioned. Thanks for pointing

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your solution sounds like great.But i can only get one combination, weather  there is a better way if i want to  get all the combinations?

Comment: Did you check my solution inside the code snippet ? There if you call *canFormContinuousNums(2,array)* and get 1, it means you have [0,1] in your array, if you get 2 it means you have [1,3], if you get 3 it means you have [0,1] AND [1,3], if you get 4 it means you have [3,4], if you get 6 it means you have [1,3] AND [3,4], if you get 7 it means you have [0,1], [1,3] AND [3,4] and if you get 0 it means you have no combination.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

#### Logic:

- Find the index where number is to be inserted.
- Now loop over partial range:
- Start from `0` or `index-2` to capture previous elements.
- Stop loop at `index + 2`. This may result in exceeding bounds.
- Now validate, if value exists and the difference between next and current element is `1` increment `count`.
- Now compare if count is greater than on equal to your required continuous length (*2 in your case*) and return accordingly.

```js
function canMakeContinuous(arr, num) {
  if(arr.indexOf(num) > -1) return false
  var copy = arr.slice();
  var index = 0;
  arr.some(function(item, i) {
    index = i;
    if (item > num) {
      return true;
    }
  });
  copy.splice(index, 0, num)
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = Math.max(index - 2, 0); i < index + 3; i++) {
    if (copy[i + 1] !== undefined && copy[i + 1] - copy[i] === 1) {
      count++;
    } else if (count < 2) {
      count = 0;
    }
  }
  return count > 1
}


var array = [2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 0];

canMakeContinuous(array, 1)
canMakeContinuous(array, 6)
canMakeContinuous(array, 5)
canMakeContinuous(array, 9)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!But maybe there are some bugs if i input like this : var array = [0,2,1,4,6]; var num = 0; the codes will give me a mistaken result.As 0,1,2 can also make continuous.if i var array = [0,2,1,4,6,7,8];var num = 8;i also get wrong answer.

Comment: Then you will have to sort the array

Comment: I really appreciate your help!